# MongoDB how to check for double existence in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I would like to know how can I check the existence of two objects with mongoDB and C#.

I know how to do it for 1 object:

```
foreach (BsonDocument item in collection.Find(Query.Exists("Boiling point")))
```

But i have no idea how to check on two objects.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, two objects? Two conditions?

Comment: yes, i want to check for the existence of 2 keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Query.And` to search more than one condition.

```
foreach (BsonDocument item in collection.Find(
    Query.And(
        Query.Exists("Boiling point"), 
        Query.Exists("Freezing Point")))
```

A complete list is available in the online documentation [here](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/).